# Hawtio simple plugin example - tab is not visible

Tags: plugins, hawtio

I am trying to develop a custom hawtio plugin. I have custom WAR deployed in Tomcat based on hawtio-default 1.4.37. It works correctly

I built simple-plugin.war following  https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/simple-plugin instruction (no changes are done) and deployed it in the same Tomcat.

There are no errors, all logs are clean, I can see simple-plugin as plugin of hawtio in JMX bean, however no new tab is visible (although as I guess from .js code "Simple" tab should appear)

Any idea? Is it something to do with perspectives?

Edit:

Just checked the browser console and seen 404 error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myhawtio/plugin/ 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that my custom WAR is not correctly reconfigured

Edit 2:

Downloaded and deployed clean hawtio-default-1.4.37.war - simple-plugin works, "Simple" tab is visible

Downloaded and deployed clean sample-1.4.37.war - simple-plugin does not work, tab is not visible and get 404 error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sample-1.4.37/plugin 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 for /hawtio/plugin then you're missing the PluginServlet from your war, or at least it isn't running -> https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-system/src/main/java/io/hawt/web/PluginServlet.java

This servlet is how the frontend discovers any additional plugins to load.  I'd suggest comparing your web.xml with the one from hawtio-web and make sure this class is getting loaded.

Comment: Correct, hawtio-default 1.4.37 I used as a base lacks io.hawt.web.PluginServlet. I added it and now it works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You must make sure to install the simple plugin using the same name as its configured in the web.xml file.

In the web.xml the context path gets set when you build the example from:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/simple-plugin/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml#L14

By default that is generated as

```
<context-param>
    <description>Plugin's path on the server</description>
    <param-name>plugin-context</param-name>
    <param-value>/simple-plugin</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So that means you should install the war as `simple-plugin` in Apache Tomcat, eg rename the .war file to `simple-plugin.war`

Comment: Thank you, Claus. The name of WAR is correct (simple-plugin.war) in my case. Actually it work correctly with one distribution (bare hawtio web application - hawtio-default-1.4.37.war) and does not work with the other distribution (a hawtio web application - sample-1.4.37.war)